# Creating Dynamic UI component : Angular 2 & Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, scripting

i have tried multiple ways on parsing data from my ts file to another. I am using array and object. However , when i console log , it stated that there is no data was being parsed .

for an example , i want to parse data in array list from its parent file to child file.

The first code, i have is where developer will input data in, for an example. in logo , they want to use icon class called "md-alarm" , they will type in inside public LeftMenu : a[]...

```
export class HeaderComponent{

private _headerConfig:any = {

    title:"",

    LeftMenu : [
    {logo: "md-alarm"},
    ],

};
```

This is where my the ui logic will process. The thing is , i am unsure how am i suppose to write the syntax out in order for me to parse the data that was being input on the above code to here. Im am sure my syntax is wrong below. :(

```
export class KdHeader implements OnInit {

public title: any = {};
public leftButton : any = [
                            {logo:""}
                          ];




private _defaultConfig: any = {
    title: "Please Specify You title",

    leftButton :[
    { icon : "md-alarm" },
    ]

}; 
{
@Input() config: any;

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.config);
    if(this.config.leftMenu.logo == ""){
        this.leftButton.logo = this._defaultConfig.leftButton.icon;
    } else {
        this.leftButton.logo = this.config._LeftButton.logo;
    }
  if(this.config.LeftMenu)
```

Lastly, Eventually , it will bind whatever that was input by user to html file show below

```
     <ion-buttons start class='ion-btn-start'>
        <button ion-button class="logo-btn">
            <ion-icon name="{{leftButton.logo}}">
            </ion-icon>
        </button>


          <!-- Button 2 -->
       <!--  <button ion-button class="btn2-icon">
            <ion-icon name="{{button2}}">
            </ion-icon>
        </button> -->
     </ion-buttons>
```

Comment: If you are using ionic, You can pass data from the parent page to child page using navParams. Pls check this link : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavPush/

Comment: i am creating a reusable component. I have to create a dynamic HeaderComponent that wraps ionic2 itself.

Comment: Do you want the header config that the user inputs to be persisted or the user should input every time they open the app?

Comment: The developer can input any icon , and it will display . They should not input everytime they open the app. i am creating a reusable UI component. so basically , if the there is no input inside leftMenu : [logo:""] in my first ts file. it will display default logo which can be found inside my second menu at _defaultConfig : any { leftMenu : [icon : "md-alarm"]}. I was told to use object.assign but i am not sure how to use it eventhough i tried. cause the biggest problem i am facing is that  , i dont pretty quite know how to display the output to my html ion-icon name using string interpolation

Comment: Eventthough i tried to bind it, it returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

So, As i understand there are two issues.
1. To pass the data from first file to second & persist it. for this, you can save the _headerConfig json to localStorage or Sqlite using the Sqlite plugin and fetch the data on ngOnInit and assign it to the variable. This data from the local storage can then be accessed across the application.
2. For displaying the output. i.e., to bind the icon name to the name attribute,
instead of name="{{leftButton.logo}}" use : [name]="leftButton.logo".